What is the cost of a machine clear in X86?
What is the cost of a machine clear on the X86 due to a memory order violation?
When busy spinning (for lowest possible latency), it could happen that the core runs into a memory order violation (due to the out of order execution and branch prediction that fills the instruction pipeline).
When such a memory order violation is detected, a machine clear is issued which nukes the instruction pipeline.
The X86 has a PAUSE instruction that inserts a bubble in the pipeline to deal with this situation. The size of the bubble has been changing. It was something like 10 cycles till Skylake where it was increased to 140 and later it got decreased:
https://www.reddit.com/r/intel/comments/hogk2n/research_on_the_impact_of_intel_pause_instruction/
My question is: what is the cost of a machine clear? How much latency is incurred and is it less than the latency caused by the PAUSE?
In the system HT is disabled; so the fact that PAUSE gives the hypersibling more resources isn't relevant.

The new value of a cache line will become visible on average half way through pause's sleep time.  So the worst-case inter-core latency cost is an extra 140 cycles (on Skylake and later), but the average is less.  vs. a machine_clears.memory_ordering event not even starting until after the event you want to react to.  I don't have numbers for the pipeline cost, but it's probably less than 140 cycles.  Maybe somewhat similar to branch mispredict, which is like 15-20 cycles, although IDK how soon it gets detected; maybe not until retirement unlike for branches which get detected at exec.
